# create database with use of flasksql alchemy in google cloud sql server

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql

I try to connect to database in gcp postresql SQL-server from windows local machine. I connected with such command:

```
cloud_sql_proxy -instances=<myProject:us-central1:myInstance>=tcp:0.0.0.0:8080 
& 
psql -U postgres -h <Public IP address>
```

Now I need to make database with use of `sqlalchemy`.
I tried

```
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'postgres+psycopg2://<db_user>:<db_pass>@<Public IP address>/<myInstance>?host=<myProject:us-central1:myInstance>'
```

after command `flask db migrate` I got an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "<myProject:us-central1:myInstance>" to address: Unknown host
```

THen I tried to make / at the end of myProject:us-central1:myInstance I got another error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Invalid argument (0x00002726/10022)
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "?host=<myProject:us-central1:myInstance>//.s.PGSQL.8080"?
```

at the end I put `.s.PGSQL.8080` and got the same error:

```
server: Invalid argument (0x00002726/10022)
            Is the server running locally and accepting
            connections on Unix domain socket "?host=<myProject:us-central1:myInstance>//.s.PGSQL.8080/.s.PGSQL.8080"?
```

Tell me please how should I solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

SQLAlchemy just wants to use the IP to the instance, not the connection name. It doesn't know how to translate a connection name (the bit with <project_id>:<region>:<instance_id>) into an instance to connect to. That's one of the things the proxy does.

So you have a couple options:

1. Keep using the proxy the way you are, although I wouldn't set the tcp to 0.0.0.0:8080 as that's not the usual way you'd want to be connecting to a SQL database. I'd do it like: `cloud_sql_proxy -instances=<myProject:us-central1:myInstance>=tcp:5432 &`. Then in your SQLAlchemy code just connect as if you're connecting to the db locally. When you start the proxy, you should get a message like "Listening on port 127.0.0.1:5432". That's then what your application would connect to.
2. Connect directly to the database from SQLAlchemy. If your database is set up for public IP, you can authorize the networks you want to connect from in the Google Cloud Console (or command line if you're comfortable on command line using the gcloud tool). If you go this route, you'd grab the public IP from your Cloud SQL instance's overview page and use that in the connection code.

I'd heavily recommend option 1, as option 2 doesn't inherently have a lot of security in place. You'd have to add security yourself, for example, by setting up your instance to only use SSL connections, and then generate the keys and use the private key in your SQLAlchemy code to ensure a secure connection. The proxy handles all that for you.